Python Multiprocessing seems to require a seemingly wrong combination of imports
I have the following code using the multiprocessor package
print ('cpu count=',multiprocessing.cpu_count())

event = multiprocessing.Event() # Assign an event object
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for serverNum in range (2):
        pool.apply_async(funcCall, (event, lock, serverNum))

When the code is preceeded with
import multiprocessing

I get the error "Pool" is not defined
If I include instead
from multiprocessing import Event, Lock, Pool

I get the error
print ('cpu count=',multiprocessing.cpu_count())
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined. Did you forget to import 'multiprocessing'?
When include
from multiprocessing import Event, Lock, Pool
import multiprocessing

It brings in everything I need. But it seems wrong to include the module as well as including the names of individual functions in the module.

I agree with your frustration; I feel the same way about Python's import system. But that's how it is. You don't actually have a question here. Is the question implicit? "Why is the language designed like this?" Or are you just complaining?

Shouldn't you just be using multiprocessing.Pool, just like you did it for multiprocessing.Event() and multiprocessing.Lock(), that will remove the need to import each individually, or if you want to import each then import cpu_count as well and use directly cpu_count().
Approach 1: with the complete module
import multiprocessing
print ('cpu count=', multiprocessing.cpu_count())

event = multiprocessing.Event() # Assign an event object
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for serverNum in range (2):
        pool.apply_async(funcCall, (event, lock, serverNum))

Approach 2: with individual imports
from multiprocessing import Event, Pool, Lock, cpu_count
print ('cpu count=', cpu_count())

event = Event() # Assign an event object
lock = Lock()

with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for serverNum in range (2):
        pool.apply_async(funcCall, (event, lock, serverNum))


Also, if the token multiprocessing is inconveniently long, one can use the statement import multiprocessing as mp, and replace all further instances of multiprocessing in the code with mp.

It's all a question of personal taste. import loads the module and binds either its global namespace or some of its variables to a variable (or variables) in your namespace. It's common to either keep the namespace or import every object you are going to use.
In your case you could keep the namespace with import multiprocessing and use multiprocessing.Pool to avoid the error. Or, you could add cpu_count to the list in from multiprocessing import Event, Lock, Pool. Your third hybrid solution is also okay, even if you don't find it aesthetically pleasing.
I prefer keeping namespaces which can make the code more clear in the long run. But in the multiprocessing case, I use an alias. It's like when calling pandas pd and numpy np. I think it would work well for you also.
import multiprocessing as mp

then its mp.Pool, mp.Lock, etc...
